# Compute stock price probability distribution from option data (IB method & negative probabilities issue)

Tags: options, probability

I'm using a procedure as described in the interactive brokers article here (https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5910&ns=T) to compute a probability distribution from option (call) prices.

In essence you solve a very simple system of two linear equations at each strike.

The issue is I get negative probabilities coming out of it.

I'm looking for a simple and robust procedure to do this estimation. Thoughts?

Comment: you could use breeden litzenberger. Any specific reason why you would not want to use breeden litzenberger ?http://math5021.weebly.com/uploads/3/6/3/0/3630523/breeden-litzenberger.pdf

Comment: I tried -- I get wildly fluctuating values including negative values that look nothing like a PD. Any help?

`code
    nstrikes = nrow(x.calls)
    x.pd <- rep(0, nstrikes)
    for (i in 2:(nstrikes-1))
    {
        call.cur <- x.calls$mid[i]
        call.prev <- x.calls$mid[i-1]
        call.next <- x.calls$mid[i+1]
        call.h <- ((x.calls$strike[i] - x.calls$strike[i-1]) + (x.calls$strike[i+1] - x.calls$strike[i])) / 2
        butterfly.val <- (call.next - 2 * call.cur + call.prev) / call.h
        x.pd[i] <- butterfly.val
    }

`

Comment: It could be that you get negative probabilities because of the values for the mid. If the spread is very wide, and 1 bid (or 1 offer moves). Then that can change the mid a lot.